# Luna Service for media in LG webOS 3.0 TV App

Tags: javascript, media, webos, lg

Need to know what the below service does.

luna://com.webos.media service (Note: It's not available in Luna service documentation)

I'm looking for language change in Subtitle/Audio for a channel. Please guide me through this.

Please refer the below sample.

```
 webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.media", {
    method:"selectTrack",
    parameters: { "type": "audio", "index": index, "mediaId": mediaId },
      onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log("[succes] select audio track " + index);
      },
      onFailure: function (result) {
        console.log( "[fail][" + result.errorCode + "] " + result.errorText );
        }
 });
```

Please mention the other available methods for this API.

Comment: That's a Partner-level API call.  You should check with your contact at LG if you're permitted to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have successfully used this method to switch between subtitles and audio tracks for LG WebOS devices.

You can refer to this link to improve:
https://github.com/webosose/umediaserver/blob/master/src/server/uMediaserver.cpp

```
/**
@page com_webos_media com.webos.media
@{
@section com_webos_media_selectTrack selectTrack
Selects Track
@par Parameters
Name | Required | Type | Description
-----|--------|------|----------
mediaId  | yes | String  | media id assigned to this media.
type     | yes | String  | track type: video, audio and subtitle.
index    | yes | Integer  | track index to select.
@par Returns(Call)
Name | Required | Type | Description
-----|--------|------|----------
returnValue | yes | Boolean | true if successful, false otherwise.
errorCode   | no  | Integer | errorCode only if returnValue is false.
errorText   | no  | String  | errorText only if returnValue is false.
mediaId     | yes | String  | media id assigned to this media.
```